# Debugging Rust Lifetime Errors

Tags: rust

I am trying to debug the following Rust code, but I am struggling with how to correctly specify the lifetimes:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum FooBox<'a, T> {
    Ref(&'a Foo<T>),
    Own(Foo<T>),
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Foo<T> {
    data: T,
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    /// Construct a new Foo
    pub fn new(data: T) -> Self {
        Self { data }
    }
}

pub trait Bar<C, P>
where
    C: Clone,
    P: Clone,
{
    fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (&'a C, FooBox<P>)>
    where
        C: 'a,
        P: 'a;
}

pub struct MyBar<'a, C, F0, F1, P0, P1>
where
    C: Clone,
    F0: Bar<C, P0>,
    F1: Bar<C, P1>,
    P0: Clone,
    P1: Clone,
{
    bar0: &'a F0,
    bar1: &'a F1,

    // Used for type checking at compile time
    c: PhantomData<C>,
    p0: PhantomData<P0>,
    p1: PhantomData<P1>,
}

impl<'a, C, F0, F1, P0, P1> MyBar<'a, C, F0, F1, P0, P1>
where
    C: Clone,
    F0: Bar<C, P0>,
    F1: Bar<C, P1>,
    P0: Clone,
    P1: Clone,
{
    /// Construct a new MyBar
    pub fn new(bar0: &'a F0, bar1: &'a F1) -> Self {
        Self {
            bar0,
            bar1,
            c: PhantomData,
            p0: PhantomData,
            p1: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, C, F0, F1, P0, P1> Bar<C, (FooBox<'a, P0>, FooBox<'a, P1>)>
    for MyBar<'a, C, F0, F1, P0, P1>
where
    C: Clone + PartialOrd,
    F0: Bar<C, P0>,
    F1: Bar<C, P1>,
    P0: Clone + PartialEq,
    P1: Clone + PartialEq,
{
    fn iter<'b>(&'b self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (&C, FooBox<(FooBox<'a, P0>, FooBox<'a, P1>)>)>
    where
        C: 'b,
        P0: 'b,
        P1: 'b,
    {
        MyBarIter::new(self.bar0.iter(), self.bar1.iter())
    }
}

/// Iterator for an MyBar
pub struct MyBarIter<'a, C, I0, I1, P0, P1>
where
    C: Clone + PartialOrd + 'a,
    I0: Iterator<Item = (&'a C, FooBox<'a, P0>)>,
    I1: Iterator<Item = (&'a C, FooBox<'a, P1>)>,
    P0: Clone + PartialEq + 'a,
    P1: Clone + PartialEq + 'a,
{
    iter0: I0,
    iter1: I1,
}

impl<'a, C, I0, I1, P0, P1> MyBarIter<'a, C, I0, I1, P0, P1>
where
    C: Clone + PartialOrd,
    I0: Iterator<Item = (&'a C, FooBox<'a, P0>)>,
    I1: Iterator<Item = (&'a C, FooBox<'a, P1>)>,
    P0: Clone + PartialEq,
    P1: Clone + PartialEq,
{
    /// Construct a new iterator from the given MyBar
    pub fn new(iter0: I0, iter1: I1) -> Self {
        Self { iter0, iter1 }
    }
}

impl<'a, C, I0, I1, P0, P1> Iterator for MyBarIter<'a, C, I0, I1, P0, P1>
where
    C: Clone + PartialOrd,
    I0: Iterator<Item = (&'a C, FooBox<'a, P0>)>,
    I1: Iterator<Item = (&'a C, FooBox<'a, P1>)>,
    P0: Clone + PartialEq,
    P1: Clone + PartialEq,
{
    type Item = (&'a C, FooBox<'a, (FooBox<'a, P0>, FooBox<'a, P1>)>);

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let next0 = self.iter0.next();
        let next1 = self.iter1.next();

        if let (Some((c0, p0)), Some((_, p1))) = (next0, next1) {
            return Some((c0, FooBox::Own(Foo::new((p0, p1)))));
        }

        return None;
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get the following error message:

```rust
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:84:9
   |
69 | impl<'a, C, F0, F1, P0, P1> Bar<C, (FooBox<'a, P0>, FooBox<'a, P1>)>
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
78 |     fn iter<'b>(&'b self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (&C, FooBox<(FooBox<'a, P0>, FooBox<'a, P1>)>)>
   |             -- lifetime `'b` defined here
...
84 |         MyBarIter::new(self.bar0.iter(), self.bar1.iter())
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method was supposed to return data with lifetime `'a` but it is returning data with lifetime `'b`
   |
   = help: consider adding the following bound: `'b: 'a`
```

As far as I can tell, references returned by the iterator returned by `self.bar0.iter()` and `self.bar1.iter()` live at least as long as `self.bar0` and `self.bar1`, which have lifetime `'a`, but the compiler does not know this. How do I specify the lifetimes correctly so that the compiler is happy?

Comment: We need to do some lifetime alignments. Try in Bar  `fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (&'a C, FooBox<'a, P>)> + 'a` and in MyBar `fn iter<'b>(&'b self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (&C, FooBox<(FooBox<'a, P0>, FooBox<'a, P1>)>)> + 'b`

Comment: As far as I can tell, that did not work. I am still seeing the same error. Here is the Rust playground with the code: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0c80e76afbf68eca8a370eeb11a2cd83

Comment: Your `Bar` trait looks suspiciously close to a `impl IntoIterator for &T`, if you can, do that instead of rolling your own trait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can work if you can simply add a lifetime to your trait, in cases where you don't need it you can specify `'static`:

```rust
pub trait Bar<'a, C, P> {
    fn iter<'b>(&'b self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (&'b C, FooBox<P>)>
    where
        C: 'b,
        P: 'b,
        'b: 'a;
}

impl<'a, C, F0, F1, P0, P1> MyBar<'a, C, F0, F1, P0, P1>
where
    C: Clone,
    F0: Bar<'static, C, P0>,
    F1: Bar<'static, C, P1>,
    P0: Clone,
    P1: Clone,
{
    /// Construct a new MyBar
    pub fn new(bar0: &'a F0, bar1: &'a F1) -> Self {
        Self {
            bar0,
            bar1,
            _m: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, C, F0, F1, P0, P1> Bar<'a, C, (FooBox<'a, P0>, FooBox<'a, P1>)>
    for MyBar<'a, C, F0, F1, P0, P1>
where
    C: Clone + PartialOrd,
    F0: Bar<'a, C, P0>,
    F1: Bar<'a, C, P1>,
    P0: Clone + PartialEq,
    P1: Clone + PartialEq,
{
    fn iter<'b>(&'b self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (&C, FooBox<(FooBox<'a, P0>, FooBox<'a, P1>)>)>
    where
        C: 'b,
        P0: 'b,
        P1: 'b,
        'b: 'a,
    {
        MyBarIter::new(self.bar0.iter(), self.bar1.iter())
    }
}
```

then you can specify the correct lifetime dependency `'b: 'a` in the trait declaration.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=379492e44259577db147667927d1d355)