# The method `into_iter` exists for reference but its trait bounds were not satisfied

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement `IntoIterator` for a struct (called `LeveledBar`). This struct has two references to `Bar`s, so to call `into_iter()`, it must first call `into_iter()` on each of its children.

```rust
pub enum FooBox<'a, T> {
    Bound(&'a T),
    Unbound(T),
}

pub trait Bar {
    type Foo;
}

pub struct LeveledBar<'a, B0, B1>
where
    B0: Bar,
    B1: Bar,
{
    bar0: &'a B0,
    bar1: &'a B1,
}

impl<'a, B0, B1, T0, T1> LeveledBar<'a, B0, B1>
where
    B0: Bar<Foo = T0>,
    B1: Bar<Foo = T1>,
{
    pub fn new(bar0: &'a B0, bar1: &'a B1) -> Self {
        Self {
            bar0,
            bar1,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, B0, B1, T0, T1> Bar for LeveledBar<'a, B0, B1>
where
    B0: Bar<Foo = T0>,
    B1: Bar<Foo = T1>,
    T0: 'a,
    T1: 'a,
{
    type Foo = (FooBox<'a, T0>, FooBox<'a, T1>);
}

impl<'a, 'b, B0, B1, T0, T1> IntoIterator for &'b LeveledBar<'a, B0, B1>
where
    B0: Bar<Foo = T0>,
    B1: Bar<Foo = T1>,
    for<'c> &'c B0: IntoIterator<Item = FooBox<'c, T0>>,
    for<'c> &'c B1: IntoIterator<Item = FooBox<'c, T1>>,
    T0: 'b,
    T1: 'b,
{
    type Item = FooBox<'b, (FooBox<'b, T0>, FooBox<'b, T1>)>;
    type IntoIter = LeveledBarIter<'b, <&'b B0 as IntoIterator>::IntoIter, <&'b B1 as IntoIterator>::IntoIter, T0, T1>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        LeveledBarIter::new(self.bar0.into_iter(), self.bar1.into_iter())
    }

}

pub struct LeveledBarIter<'a, I0, I1, T0, T1>
where
    I0: Iterator<Item = FooBox<'a, T0>>,
    I1: Iterator<Item = FooBox<'a, T1>>,
    T0: 'a,
    T1: 'a,
{
    iter0: I0,
    iter1: I1,
}

impl<'a, I0, I1, T0, T1> LeveledBarIter<'a, I0, I1, T0, T1>
where
    I0: Iterator<Item = FooBox<'a, T0>>,
    I1: Iterator<Item = FooBox<'a, T1>>,
{
    pub fn new(iter0: I0, iter1: I1) -> Self {
        Self {
            iter0,
            iter1,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, I0, I1, T0, T1> Iterator for LeveledBarIter<'a, I0, I1, T0, T1>
where
    I0: Iterator<Item = FooBox<'a, T0>>,
    I1: Iterator<Item = FooBox<'a, T1>>,
{
    type Item = FooBox<'a, (FooBox<'a, T0>, FooBox<'a, T1>)>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        None
    }
}

pub struct RootBar<T>
{
    t: T,
}

impl<T> RootBar<T>
{
    pub fn new(t: T) -> Self {
        Self { t }
    }
}

impl<T> Bar for RootBar<T>
{
    type Foo = T;
}

impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a RootBar<T>
{
    type Item = FooBox<'a, T>;
    type IntoIter = RootBarIter<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        RootBarIter::new(self)
    }

}

pub struct RootBarIter<'a, T>
{
    bar: &'a RootBar<T>,
}

impl<'a, T> RootBarIter<'a, T>
{
    pub fn new(bar: &'a RootBar<T>) -> Self {
        Self { bar }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for RootBarIter<'a, T>
{
    type Item = FooBox<'a, T>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        None
    }
}

fn main() {
    let root0 = RootBar::new(0);
    let root1 = RootBar::new(1);
    let root2 = RootBar::new(2);
    
    let leveled01 = LeveledBar::new(&root0, &root1);
    let leveled012 = LeveledBar::new(&leveled01, &root2);
    let mut iter = (&leveled012).into_iter();
}
```

You can find the Rust playground example [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c2acbc47279137dd1ac247bb92ac4d9b).

The error message is:

```
 Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0599]: the method `into_iter` exists for reference `&LeveledBar<'_, LeveledBar<'_, RootBar<{integer}>, RootBar<{integer}>>, RootBar<{integer}>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:152:34
    |
10  | pub struct LeveledBar<'a, B0, B1>
    | ---------------------------------
    | |
    | doesn't satisfy `_: IntoIterator`
    | doesn't satisfy `_: Iterator`
...
152 |     let mut iter = (&leveled012).into_iter();
    |                                  ^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `&&LeveledBar<'_, LeveledBar<'_, RootBar<{integer}>, RootBar<{integer}>>, RootBar<{integer}>>: Iterator`
            which is required by `&&LeveledBar<'_, LeveledBar<'_, RootBar<{integer}>, RootBar<{integer}>>, RootBar<{integer}>>: IntoIterator`
            `&mut &LeveledBar<'_, LeveledBar<'_, RootBar<{integer}>, RootBar<{integer}>>, RootBar<{integer}>>: Iterator`
            which is required by `&mut &LeveledBar<'_, LeveledBar<'_, RootBar<{integer}>, RootBar<{integer}>>, RootBar<{integer}>>: IntoIterator`
            `LeveledBar<'_, LeveledBar<'_, RootBar<{integer}>, RootBar<{integer}>>, RootBar<{integer}>>: Iterator`
            which is required by `LeveledBar<'_, LeveledBar<'_, RootBar<{integer}>, RootBar<{integer}>>, RootBar<{integer}>>: IntoIterator`
            `&mut LeveledBar<'_, LeveledBar<'_, RootBar<{integer}>, RootBar<{integer}>>, RootBar<{integer}>>: Iterator`
            which is required by `&mut LeveledBar<'_, LeveledBar<'_, RootBar<{integer}>, RootBar<{integer}>>, RootBar<{integer}>>: IntoIterator`
note: the trait `Iterator` must be implemented
   --> /playground/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/iter/traits/iterator.rs:75:1
    |
75  | pub trait Iterator {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to previous error
```

I have tried:

1. Not including a main function: the source seems to compile fine.
2. Create a `LeveledBar` whose children are both `RootBar`s: everything seems fine (see `L151` [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=22b887d071689d6429149281f90ed299).
3. Simplify the code further to remove the generic `T`: everything seems fine (see [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8fb849c2e6edeaa9070bf885479e0f6f)).

Comment: From some tinkering around, this smells like a compiler bug, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You should [edit] the question to include the [mre].

Comment: I edited the post a little bit, but the code is still quite long. Anything else I remove (e.g. see 3. above) no longer reproduces the error. Any advice on how to further minimize it would also be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the intent here. into_iter is usually used for an iterator that consumes the value

Comment: On a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77849598/debugging-rust-lifetime-errors), someone recommended that I use `IntoIterator` instead of defining my own trait for the iterator. Also, I read that if the type implements `IntoIterator` then it can be used with the `for` loop syntax. Should I be implementing some other trait here?

Comment: "I edited the post a little bit, but the code is still quite long." — It's *much* more important that the code is part of the question (not on another site) and reproduces the problem, than that it is short. Accordingly, I've edited the question to include the full code you had in the playground link.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the plan you have for your iterators doesn't compose with itself. You defined the iterator item type in your `IntoIterator` implementation as:

```rust
    type Item = (&'a T0, &'a T1);
```

But if `B0` is itself a `LeveledBar`, as in your `main()` example, then `B0`'s iterator item type is `(&i32, &i32)`, which is **not a reference**, so it can't be equal to `&'a T0`. (And it can't be a reference, since a reference returned by an iterator must be to some value that already existed in memory independent of the iterator — which this tuple of references isn't.)

The solution is to remove the restriction that it be a reference, which is most easily done by not restricting the item type at all:

```rust
impl<'a, B0, B1> IntoIterator for &'a LeveledBar<'a, B0, B1>
where
    B0: Bar,
    B1: Bar,
    &'a B0: IntoIterator,
    &'a B1: IntoIterator,
{
    type Item = (
        <&'a B0 as std::iter::IntoIterator>::Item,
        <&'a B1 as std::iter::IntoIterator>::Item,
    );
    ...
```

Now for your `main()` example case, the item type will be `((&'a i32, &'a i32), &'a i32)`. (**Not** `(&'a (&'a i32, &'a i32), &'a i32)`, which is — well, not strictly impossible to create, but difficult and probably unnecessary.)

Notice I've also made all the lifetimes the same, `'a`. This is because keeping them distinct does you no good when you are traversing a recursive structure of immutable references — you'd get a bunch of "does not live long enough" errors until you added enough lifetime bounds that the lifetimes were the same anyway.

Now, I notice that the item type suggests you intend to pair up elements, so I'll also *guess* that you can replace your `LeveledBarIter` with `std::iter::Zip` and get the same results. (That's just a guess, and if it's wrong, put `LeveledBarIter` back, but get rid of its `T0` and `T1` type parameters.) That makes the complete implementation:

```rust
impl<'a, B0, B1> IntoIterator for &'a LeveledBar<'a, B0, B1>
where
    B0: Bar,
    B1: Bar,
    &'a B0: IntoIterator,
    &'a B1: IntoIterator,
{
    type Item = (
        <&'a B0 as std::iter::IntoIterator>::Item,
        <&'a B1 as std::iter::IntoIterator>::Item,
    );
    type IntoIter =
        std::iter::Zip<<&'a B0 as IntoIterator>::IntoIter, <&'a B1 as IntoIterator>::IntoIter>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.bar0.into_iter().zip(self.bar1.into_iter())
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that in my effort to simplify, I removed something that was important. I have updated the post with my original code. As you can see, the &Ts were actually in an enum that could own or refer to a value, meaning that, I think, this does not solve the original problem.

Comment: Also, do you have suggestions for how to debug this kind of error (besides staring at it very hard)?

Comment: @student1868 My suggested changes still compile when applied to your revised code (with `FooBox`), so I don't see a problem. Perhaps you're having trouble implementing the `RootBarIter`? You'll have to either have its item type be a reference, return the `FooBox::Bound` variant, or return a clone of the `FooBox`.